# How to use hitTestPoint correctly AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, hittest

Hey everyone so I am just trying to understand this function and how to use it properly. I have read a good amount of information on it, with such methods being holding points of the object that you are using for the hitTestPoint in an array etc...

But I know there has to be an easier way correct?

I have my code setup like this so far but I don't get any trace:

```
private function checkPlayerHitBottom():void 
    {

        if (_Player.hitTestPoint(bottom.x, bottom.y, true))
        {
            trace("hit");
        }
    }
```

So the `_Player` is a ship Movie Clip and the `bottom` is the obstacle that is a square but I extrude this square up so it looks like a hill. Now I can't use the hitTestObject because trying to do it with a hill the boundary box would mess everything up since the sides of the hill are lower and the highest point of the hill is where the boundary box will make its outline if you understand what I am saying.

So how can I use the hitTestPoint to check the whole outline of the `bottom` or its exact pixels I guess you can say.

Comment: An image of the ship and the part you're trying to test would be nice.

Comment: Of course sorry about that I will post them up right now.